# Python Avro avro.io.AvroTypeException The datum is not an example of schema

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, avro

I searched quite a lot before asking this question and looks like I am stuck and therefore asking question here. I know such type of errors are encountered when Schema and object are not a match, maybe some datatype is missing or have other type of value for a field.

However, I believe my case is different.
My application is simple, which only serialize and deserialize an object into avro

My DataClass:

```py
from time import time
from faker import Faker
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

from dataclasses_avroschema import AvroModel

Faker.seed(0)
fake = Faker()


@dataclass
class Head(AvroModel):
    msgId: str = field()
    msgCode: str = field()

    @staticmethod
    def fakeMe():
        return Head(fake.md5(),
                fake.pystr(min_chars=5, max_chars=5)
            )


@dataclass
class Message(AvroModel):
    head: Head = field()
    status: bool = field()

    class Meta:
        namespace = "me.com.Message.v1"

    def fakeMe(self):
        self.head = Head.fakeMe()
        self.bool = fake.pybool()
```

Now the script that runs the serialization:

```py
import json, io as mainio
from dto.temp_schema import Message
from avro import schema, datafile, io as avroio

obj = Message(None, True)
obj.fakeMe()

schema_obj = schema.parse(json.dumps(Message.avro_schema_to_python()))

buf = mainio.BytesIO()
writer = datafile.DataFileWriter(buf, avroio.DatumWriter(), schema_obj)
writer.append(obj)
writer.flush()
buf.seek(0)
data = buf.read()

print("serialized avro: ", data)
```

When I run this I get following error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/office/Documents/projects/msg-bench/scrib.py", line 28, in <module>
    writer.append(obj)
  File "/Users/office/opt/anaconda3/envs/benchenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/avro/datafile.py", line 329, in append
    self.datum_writer.write(datum, self.buffer_encoder)
  File "/Users/office/opt/anaconda3/envs/benchenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/avro/io.py", line 771, in write
    raise AvroTypeException(self.writer_schema, datum)


avro.io.AvroTypeException: The datum Message(head=Head(msgId='f112d652ecf13dacd9c78c11e1e7f987', msgCode='cYzVR'), status=True) is not an example of the schema {
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Message",
  "namespace": "me.com.Message.v1",
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Head",
        "namespace": "me.com.Message.v1",
        "fields": [
          {
            "type": "string",
            "name": "msgId"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "name": "msgCode"
          }
        ],
        "doc": "Head(msgId: str, msgCode: str)"
      },
      "name": "head"
    },
    {
      "type": "boolean",
      "name": "status"
    }
  ],
  "doc": "Message(head: dto.temp_schema.Head, status: bool)"
}
```

Please note I am generating the schema using Dataclass Object with help of a python library:
[dataclasses-avroschema](https://github.com/marcosschroh/dataclasses-avroschema)

And still after using the same schema I am not able to serialize data to Avro.

Currently I am not sure where I am going wrong and I am new to avro. Why this won't compile?

System and Library stats:

```sh
Python==3.9.7
avro==1.10.2
avro-python3==1.10.2
dataclasses-avroschema==0.25.1
Faker==9.3.1
fastavro==1.4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to pass in the `Message` object to the standard avro library which doesn't expect that (instead it expects a dictionary). The library you are using has a section talking about serialization that you might want to take a look at: https://marcosschroh.github.io/dataclasses-avroschema/serialization/

So your script just needs to be something like this:

```py
from dto.temp_schema import Message

obj = Message(None, True)
obj.fakeMe()
print("serialized avro: ", obj.serialize())
```